# Align first letters of chapter titles in Table of Contents

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment

I am trying to create table of contents for starred version of chapter. My goal is to align all first letters of the titles to the same position. I was able to achieve that separately for single digit numbers and for double digit numbers, but I am not able to create alignment that would work for chapters with single digit numbers (1-9) and chapters with double digit numbers (10-99) at the same time.

To add horizontal spacing between numbers and titles I used two methods: non-breaking space (`~`) and `\hskip`.

Code with non-breaking space (`~`):

```
\documentclass[final,11pt]{book}
\def \mychapter#1#2{%
\chapter*{#1 \\ #2}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1~~~#2}%
}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\mychapter{8}{This chapter title}
\mychapter{9}{This chapter title}
\mychapter{10}{This chapter title}
\mychapter{11}{This chapter title}
\mychapter{20}{This chapter title}
\end{document}
```

Code with `\hskip`:

```
\documentclass[final,11pt]{book}
\def \mychapter#1#2{%
\chapter*{#1 \\ #2}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1\hskip 0.3cm#2}%
}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\mychapter{8}{This chapter title}
\mychapter{9}{This chapter title}
\mychapter{10}{This chapter title}
\mychapter{11}{This chapter title}
\mychapter{20}{This chapter title}
\end{document}
```

Closest I came to solution is by using something like this for single digit chapters (in addition to `\hskip` in basic `mychapter` definition):

```
\mychapter{9\hskip 0.2cm}{This chapter title}
```

Is there any better way to do precise alignment to first letter than that?

Comment: You can define the formatting with the help of the `titletoc` package (it is part of the `titlesec`  package.

Comment: Can you provide ``titletoc`` example to this particular case? I generally find ``titletoc`` confusing to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
\documentclass[final,11pt]{book}
\def \mychapter#1#2{%
\chapter*{#1 \\ #2}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\hbox to 1cm{#1} #2}% change 1cm to any number
}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\mychapter{8}{This chapter title}
\mychapter{9}{This chapter title}
\mychapter{10}{This chapter title}
\mychapter{11}{This chapter title}
\mychapter{20}{This chapter title}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! The way it works is by creating fixed width box around first argument and then second argument aligns to that box. Am I right? (I just want to understand solution fully).

Comment: @Rafal: Yes, exactly.